# determining the multiple solutions for GF(2) discrete logarithms of polynomials with partially known coefficients

Tags: finite-fields

I have an LFSR, essentially $x^k \mod p(x)$ for some characteristic polynomial with coefficients in GF(2), as outlined in [Clark and Weng's article](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.44.118): it has a period (= order of the associated finite field) that is a "smooth" integer (factors are small).

I know how to compute discrete logarithms using [Silver-Pohlig-Hellmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) given a completely determined polynomial, so if you told me, *Hey you! I have* $$x^{23} + x^{16} + x ^ {14} + 1 \equiv x^k \mod p(x)$$ *so what's* $k$ *?* Then I could tell you by following the algorithm.

But what if I don't know all of the coefficients, e.g. all I know is

$$a_{31}x^{31} + a_{30}x^{30} + a_{29}x^{29} + x^{23} + x^{16} + x ^ {14} + 1 \equiv x^k \mod p(x)$$

and I don't know the three unknown $a_j$'s (so $k$ has $2^3 = 8$ principal solutions). Aside from running through each of the possibilities, is there a way to figure out $k$ from one of them, and then determine the rest?

Comment: asked on mathoverflow at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287190/determining-the-multiple-solutions-for-gf2-discrete-logarithms-of-polynomial